# how could I share one config object to multi data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one config data structure  like below.

```
const config = {
  foo: 'bar',
  king: [ { val: [], name: 'saber'}, { val: [], name: 'archer'} ],
};
```

and I want to share above one to multi data object which like below.

```
var data = {
  group1: [ [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'] ],
  group2: [ [4, 5, 6], ['d', 'e', 'f'] ],
};
```

I afraid that I can't express clearly, for example, I want to get final result like this.

```
{
  group1: {
    foo: 'bar',
    king: [ {val: [1,2,3], name:'saber'}, {val: ['a','b','c'], name:'archer'} ],
  },
  group2: {
    foo: 'bar',
    king: [ {val: [4,5,6], name:'saber'}, {val: ['d','e','f'], name:'archer'} ],
  },
}
```

I try use `assign()` share one config to each data,

I write the method `compose` below but eventually I notice that `config` will be changed even if I use `Object.freeze()`, I have no idea to protect `config` variable, will you give me any suggestion?

```
var compose = function(data) {
  let mix = {};

  Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
    mix[key] = Object.assign({},
      config
    );
    mix[key].king.map(function(val, index) {
      mix[key].king[index].val = data[key][index];  // config will be changed here :(
    });
  });

  return mix;
};
```

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deep clone `config`, you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) for example:

```
'use strict'
var _ = require('lodash');

const config = {
    foo: 'bar',
    king: [{ val: [], name: 'saber' }, { val: [], name: 'archer' }],
};

var compose = function(data) {
    let mix = {};

    Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        mix[key] = _.cloneDeep(config);
        mix[key].king.map(function(val, index) {
            mix[key].king[index].val = data[key][index];  // config will be changed here :(
        });
    });

    return mix;
};

var data = {
    group1: [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
    group2: [[4, 5, 6], ['d', 'e', 'f']],
};

var out = compose(data);
console.log(require('util').inspect(out, { depth: null }));
```